# Transfer Data from one table to another in same database SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to transfer data from tableA to tableB using SSIS. These tables are in the same server and database I am using OLEDB source and OLEDB destination. However it does not write any rows and there are no errors being reported.
If I change OLEDB source to read from a different server with the same database name it works. How can I recreate the SSIS package? All help appreciated.

Comment: Use Data Viewer after your source component and see whether you are getting any rows or not  use sql profiler and then run your ssis pkg.See what query is being used to insert the rows

Comment: If the same query is used in a data source that has rows on connection manager B but not on A, that means the data supporting the query on server A does not exist. Put another way, your account is only defined on stackoverflow.com If I ran a query looking for your account on dba.stackexchange, I would find no results. Same query run here will find your account. Your task is to discover **why** this is so. Perhaps IDs are different across environments. Perhaps business process X has not run. Perhaps a special situation was manually created on server B (or A).

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use ADO.NET source and destination instead of OLEDB. 
It wouldn't be problem if the tables are on same server, and database.

Create an Execute SQL task, which truncate you destination table.
Create a dataflow task, and create an ADO.NET source and destination inside the task.
If you haven't created package before:

you can also create SSIS package with ImportExportTool like this:
[SSIS Tutorial](http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_2008_tutorial.htm), and check the Save SSIS package checkbox.
After the tool created the package, you can open it in visual studio and modify it.
The package will contain OLEDB source and destinations. It should work.

The data transformation components are very useful for a couple of issue.

Comment: and with importexport tool created package?

Comment: Try to transfer data with import export tool, without SSIS saving. Is it success?